# Get uploaded file path using on click in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, onclick

I want to get the uploaded file path when user selects a file. I tried using on change it is working fine in all browsers but do not work in Internet explorer. Is there a way to do this?

```
<input type="file">

$(document).on('click',':file',function(){
    alert($(this).val());

});
```

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/j9ran/

Comment: What jQuery version do you use? This bug is resolved in jQuery 1.4.2

Comment: you can't get file path due to security reasons no matter which browser you use. For example if file is an image with name img on alert you will always get `c:\fakepath\img.jpg`

Comment: It works fine in IE11. Maybe it's not supported in earlier versions of IE and/or jQuery. One thing is that the actual path is being replaced by '/fakepath/'.

Comment: @matewka i'm using 1.10

Comment: @UDB actually i want to extract the only name from path

Comment: @Ace from `name` do you mean only `file name` like `image1` or `file name with extension` like `image1.jpg`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the javascript's `substring` and `lastIndexOf` to extract the file name from the full path `c:\fakepath\xyz.jpg` like this:-

**html**

```
<form>
  <input id ="input" type="file" />
  <input  id="smt" type="submit" />
</form>
```

**script**

```
$('#smt').click(function(e)
{
 e.preventDefault();

 var filename=$('#input').val().substring($('#input').val().lastIndexOf('\\') + 1)

 alert(filename)

});
```

[**Click here for DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/UD_B/j9ran/1/)

**Edit as per the requirement in comment to get file name when user selects any file**

**html**

```
<input id="input" type="file" />
<p></p>
```

**script**

```
var filename;

var t;

$('#input').click(function (e) {

    $('#input').val(""); //to clear previous file name ,if any

    clearInterval(t); //if any previous interval is running 

    t = setInterval(function () {

        if ($('#input').val().length > 0) {

            filename = $('#input').val().substring($('#input').val().lastIndexOf('\\') + 1);

            clearInterval(t);

            $('p').text("");

            $('p').text("you have chosen " + filename);
        }

        else if ($('#input').val().length == 0) {

            $('p').text("");

            $('p').text("haven't chosen any file");
        }

    }, 500)


})
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/UD_B/j9ran/3/)

Comment: I wanted something like on change as i want to validate the name .tnx for the demo

Comment: @Ace can you explain in  more detail I mean `on change` of what?

Comment: when user selects a file via `input file` I want to show the name in a div. Using on change is easy but it isnt working on my IE8

Comment: @Ace i have edited the answer now have a look i hope this is what you want